# Python Pandas Dataframe - how to groupby year and summarize multiple columns in a table

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following code that summarizes revenue by year and the number of new customers acquired

```
min_dates = df.groupby(['Customer ID'])['Date'].min()
df['First Purchase Date'] = df.apply(lambda row: min_dates.loc[row['Customer ID']], axis=1)
df['New Customer'] = df['Date'] <= df['First Purchase Date']


#summarize data by year and total revenue. 
df['revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(df['revenue'])
df['Year'] = df['Date'].dt.year
number_new_customers = df.groupby(df['Year'])['New Customer'].sum()
number_existing_customers = df.groupby(df['Year'])['New Customer'].sum()
print(df['number new customers'])
```

I want the results to summarize revenue and number of customers in the same row but the data is currently being presented as two separate summaries.  Any ideas on how i can combine these?

```
OUTPUT
    >>> print(number_new_customers, total_revenue)
    Year
    2014    135
    2015    458
    2016    146
    2017    174
    2018    121
    2019    33
    Name: New Customer, dtype: float64 Year
    2014    342.74
    2015    651,227.71
    2016    3251.26
    2017    232396.94
    2018    230,087.80
    2019    2342.52
    Name: revenue, dtype: float64
    >>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mocked up some data real fast, the date is in epoch time.

```
Date,Customer ID,First Purchase Date,revenue
1339088342,4112,902531671,5.91
1539868917,3145,1256488196,9.65
1356452277,3513,1139574500,3.33
1202597342,1915,1334993455,3.90
1141307061,350,1519053454,8.43
1008402214,2096,980405444,6.83
1409224498,2606,1413988517,8.74
1372252082,3195,1127686807,3.27
1021345993,1141,1487182332,2.44
1597193200,2765,656097735,6.40
```

Use the below to convert to datetime columns

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], unit='s')
df['First Purchase Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['First Purchase Date'], unit='s')
```

Using your code to setup your columns and the below group by you can get the output provided.

```
print(df.groupby(["Year"])["New Customer", "revenue"].sum())
```

Output:

```
        New Customer  revenue
Year                       
2000           4.0    13.56
2001           2.0    14.96
2002          11.0    54.23
2003           1.0     7.13
2004           6.0    31.55
2005           5.0    20.49
2006           7.0    41.29
2007           3.0    25.11
2008           6.0    23.51
2009           1.0     4.76
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: To keep it short, i only provided the top ten rows, the output will not match if run verbatum.

Comment: Thanks Johnnyb.  Is it necessary to convert into columns?  is it possible to convert all data into columns at once?  I had imported the data into a data frame from a csv that had data separated into columns.